# Add braces around digits with a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert a string like this

```
var string = "3*v0-v1/v12"
```

to one like this using only one regex:

```
var result = "3*v[0]-v[1]*v[12]"
```

The tricky part is to add the numbers when adding the braces, something like:

```
var result = string.replace(/v\d{1,2}/g, /REGEX HERE/)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var result = string.replace(/v(\d{1,2})/g, 'v[$1]');
```

The parentheses create a group, and the `$1` is a backreference referring to that group:

[image]

Comment: In JavaScript?  Do you have the parentheses?  I can pull up a JavaScript console, enter this exactly, and it works perfectly.  The only reason you would get literal `$1` is if you omitted the parentheses.

Comment: Running it in the console just now gave me the correct answer

Comment: Some regex implementations -- not JavaScript -- use backslashes instead of dollar signs in the replacement string.  That is, you would use `\1` instead of `$1`.  But JavaScript uses dollar signs.  If there are no groups (i.e., you leave out or escape the parentheses), JavaScript won't do the substitution, and you'll be left with a literal `$1`.

Comment: my mistake, I forgot the parentheses that create the group. Now it works perfectly. Thank you!